# value of integer in for loop do not changed android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, for-loop, google-places-api

I'm developing an **Android app** which is using **Google Places API**.
Once I get all the places result, I want to sort it according to the algorithm.
Which is, the places result will only being put into the `Hash Map` if the algorithm is >= 0.
But the problem now is, when I run it, the algorithm result in the for loop did not change during the looping.

My algorithm is:
`balance = user_hour-visi-duration`.
`balance = 240-60-20 = 160`

Let's say the balance is 160, it will remain 160 until the for loop ended.
I wanted  each time of the looping, the value of balance will decreased untill negative value.
FYI, balance variable is not a local variable.

Does anybody know how to solve this?
Here is the part of the code.

```
// loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            balance = user_hour - duration - visit;
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
                            try {
                                placeDetails = googlePlaces.getPlaceDetails(p.reference);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if(placeDetails != null){

                                String statuss = placeDetails.status;

                                // check place deatils status
                                // Check for all possible status
                                if(statuss.equals("OK")){




                                        lat = gps.getLatitude();
                                        lang = gps.getLongitude();
                                        double endlat = placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lat;
                                        double endlong = placeDetails.result.geometry.location.lng;



                                        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                                        locationA.setLatitude(lat);
                                        locationA.setLongitude(lang);
                                        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                                        locationB.setLatitude(endlat);
                                        locationB.setLongitude(endlong);
                                        double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;
                                        Double dist = distance;
                                        Integer dist2 = dist.intValue();
                                        //p.distance = String.valueOf(dist2);
                                        p.distance = String.valueOf(balance);
                                        dist3 = p.distance;





                                }
                                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                                            "Sorry no place found.",
                                            false);
                                }
                                }

                                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                            if (balance > 0){

                                // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                                // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);
                                // Place name
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);
                                map.put(KEY_DISTANCE, p.distance);
                                // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                                placesListItems.add(map);


                                }

                            else {
                                //

                            }


                        }//end for loop
```

Comment: The best way to understand what's happening is to trace your code using Eclipse's debug tools.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here?

You have `balance = user_hour - duration - visit;` on the first line after your for loop. I cannot see where `user_hour`, `duration` or `visit` is declared, but I'm assuming it's outside the loop. This means it will always be the same value for each `Place` in `nearPlaces.results`. If this code is genuinely how you want it, you might as well declare it before the loop as you are pointlessly re-calculating it for every `Place`.

You also never do anything with `balance` except to print it out or set another value to it, so it's tricky to work out what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: user_hour, duration or visit are declared outside the loop. 
when line balance = user_hour - duration - visit; executed on the first line of the loop, the balance will be change right since it is global variable? 
i wanted the balance variable will be changed every time the loop occur for each Place.

Comment: @HafizMughni When you go through the loop you are not modifying `user_hour`, `duration` or `visit` and therefore the `balance` will always be the same value.

Comment: @ingo ya u are right.. how careless am i bout this small matter!!.. thanks a lot!

Comment: @HafizMughni no problem. Do you want to update your question or does it work now?

Comment: @ingo it works now.. just change the line to balance = balance -user_hour - duration - visit;. with this the value of balance will be decreasing just like i want it...